# Need SOAP API for Add/Update/Delete Air Extars in Sabre Flight Booking?

Tags: web-services, soap, sabre

We are using the **Orchestrated Air Booking** SOAP API (version 3.2.0) to book and PNR in our system.
We use the **AncillaryPriceRQ** to get the Air Extars catalog for the booked itinerary.
We want now to add Air Extras for the shopping process.
What Sabre API should we use to:
1. Add selected ancillaries to the order?
2. Update selected ancillaries of the order?
3. Delete selected ancillaries from the order?

Our workflow is:
1. BargainFinderMaxRQ (find)
2. EnhancedAirBook (book)
3. PassengerDetails (create PNR)
4. AncillaryPriceRQ (show the Air Extars catalog by the PNR).
**5. ??? (Add the selected Air Extars to the PNR).**
6. DesignatePrinterLLS (Print tickets)
7. AirTicketLLS (Issue tickets)

See above Step 5. What ws service is needed here to add the Air Extars to the PNR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UpdateReservationRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Update_Itinerary) will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

I use SabreCommandRQ and then I play with the response.

If you find a specific webService for this, let me know.